# Proving the measure of an increasing sequence of measurable sets is the limit of the measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that if $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq\cdots$ is an increasing sequence of measurable sets (so $A_j\subseteq A_{j+1}$ for every positive integer $j$), then we have
$$m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right)=\lim_{j\to\infty}m(A_j)$$

---

Here is my proof:

According to the $\sigma$-algebra property, $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$ is a measurable set, so it makes sense to talk about $m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j)$.

Firstly, I prove that $\lim_{j\to\infty}m(A_j)\leq m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j)$. This is because for any given positive integer $N$, $A_N\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_i$, according to monotonicity, we have $m(A_N)\leq m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_i)$. Take the limit,we will have $\lim_{j\to\infty}m(A_j)\leq m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j)$.

Secondly, I prove that $m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j)\leq \lim_{j\to\infty}m(A_j)$. For any given positive integer $N$, $\bigcup_{j=1}^N A_j = A_N$. According to monotonicity,we have $m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^N A_j\right)=m(A_N)\leq \lim_{j\to\infty}m(A_j)$. Take the limit, we will have $m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right) \leq \lim_{j\to\infty} m(A_j)$.

Combine the above two arguments, we will see that $$m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right)=\lim_{j\to\infty} m(A_j)$$$\Box$

---

The above is my proof, unlike many books, my proof does not use the property of countable additivity. So I doubt my proof is correct. Who can point out where are my mistakes?

Comment: At least somewhere you should remark that $m(A_j)$ is an *increasing sequence*, and so the limit exists and is less than or equal to any common bound to all terms...

Comment: First of all, you have $\lim_{N \to \infty} m(A_j)$ on the right-hand side in part of the second step. Should your $N$ be a $j$? Second of all, how do you get from $\lim_{N\to\infty} m(\cup_{j=1}^N A_j)$ to $m(\cup_{j=1}^\infty A_j)$ when taking the limit at the very end?

Comment: In the second half, you are trying to argue that $$\lim_{N\to\infty}m(\cup_{j=1}^NA_j) = m(\lim_{N\to\infty}\cup_{j=1}^NA_j) = m(\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j)$$(in order to "take the limit"). But this is *precisely* what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Hint: Write the infinite union as a disjoint union, and use countable additivity.

Comment: @MikeB: I think the OP knows the standard proof; that seems clear from the wording in his question. :)

Comment: @cardinal: Sorry: I didn't see your comment when I was writing mine (went away half-way through, came back, finished it, and posted; then yours "appeared"). My apologies if it seemed I was stepping on your toes on purpose.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: No, I knew you weren't. :) I just was wondering if my statement was a little too obtuse/Socratic. I've noticed the synchronization of how comments get posted can be strange at times.

Comment: Dear @cardinal ,thanks for your help!I think you point out the key!

Comment: Dear @ArturoMagidin ,thank you too.You also point out the key!

Comment: Does this theorem doesn't have the restriction on the measure of first set to be finite, like it's sister theorem which is about the decreasing sequence of measurable sets?

Answer (score 15):

> $m(A_N)\leq m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_i)$. Take the limit, we will have $\lim_{j\to\infty}m(A_j)\leq m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j)$.

The above is valid because if $b_j\le b$ for $j=1,2,3,\ldots$ then $\lim_j b_j \le b$.

> $m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{N}A_j)=m(A_N)\leq \lim_{j\to\infty}m(A_j)$. Take the limit, we will have $m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j)\leq \lim_{j\to\infty}m(A_j)$.

The above is **not** valid.  You claim to have "taken the limit" of $m\left( \bigcup_{j=1}^N A_j \right)$.  You cannot take a limit merely by putting $\infty$ wherever you see $N$. The question is: how do you know that
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} m\left( \bigcup_{j=1}^N A_j \right) = m\left( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \right) \text{ ???}
$$

First, notice that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ is **not** defined as a limit as $N\to\infty$ of $\bigcup_{j=1}^N A_j$.  Rather, it is defined by saying $x\in \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ if and only if $\exists j\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}\quad x\in A_j$.  And **if it were** defined as a limit, there would still be the question of continuity of the function $m$.  How would you prove that?

Here's a different way:
\begin{align}
m\left( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \right) & =  m \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \left( A_j\setminus( A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{j-1} ) \right)\right) & & \text{(Think about why this is true.)} \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{j=1}^\infty m\left( A_j\setminus( A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{j-1} ) \right) & & \text{by countable additivity of $m$} \\[10pt]
& = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^N m\left( A_j\setminus( A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{j-1} ) \right) \\[10pt]
& = \lim_{N\to\infty} m\left( \bigcup_{j=1}^N A_j\setminus( A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{j-1} ) \right) & & \text{by finite additivity of $m$} \\[10pt]
& = \lim_{N\to\infty} m(A_N).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as it is mentioned in the comments you were wrong in assuming 
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^NA_j\right)=m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right)$$
However the proof can be done without using the countably additivity property. 
Suppose $m$ is a measure defined on $\mathcal{F}$, the field generating the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{A}$, then for a general $A\in\mathcal{A}$, the outer measure is defined as
$$m^{\ast}(A)=\inf\{m(B):B\in\mathcal{F}_{\sigma},B\supset A\}$$
We can show that $m^{\ast}$ is monotone and strongly subadditive. Now let $A_n\uparrow A$.
Then as $A_n\subset A$, so $m^{\ast}(A_n)\leq m^{\ast}(A)$. So $$\lim_{n\to\infty}m^{\ast}(A_n)\leq m^{\ast}(A)$$. Now obviously we can find $B_n\in\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$ such that $$m(B_n)\leq m^{\ast}(A_n)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$$ by the definition of $m^{\ast}$. Let $$C_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k$$. Then $A_n\subset B_n\subset C_n$ and hence $\lim A_n\subset\lim C_n$ or $m^{\ast}(A)\leq m^{\ast}(\lim C_n)$. Now $\lim C_n\in \mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$ so $m^{\ast}(\lim C_n)=m(\lim C_n)$ and as $m$ is continuous from below, so $m(\lim C_n)=\lim m(C_n)$. Now $m(C_{n+1})+m(C_n\cap B_{n+1})=m(C_n)+m(B_{n+1})$. Now note that $A_n\subset C_n$ and $A_n\subset A_{n+1}\subset B_{n+1}$. So $A_n\subset C_n\cap B_{n+1}$, so $m^{\ast}(A_n)\leq m^{\ast}(C_n\cap B_{n+1})=m(C_n\cap B_{n+1})$. Thus our claim is proved. So we have $m^{\ast}(A)\leq \lim m(C_n)\leq \lim m^{\ast}(A_n)+\epsilon$. So $$m^{\ast}(A_n)\uparrow m^{\ast}(A).$$