# Limit of infinite measure union

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ be Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. It is certainly true, by monotonicity of $\mu$, that $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right)\leq \mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)$$

Is it true that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right)= \mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)?$$

I've tried to think about the case where $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)$ is infinite, but still can't find any counterexample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving the measure of an increasing sequence of measurable sets is the limit of the measures](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135050/proving-the-measure-of-an-increasing-sequence-of-measurable-sets-is-the-limit-of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely continuity from below of measures:

Set $E_n = \bigcup_1^n A_i$, $E=\bigcup_1^\infty A_i$. Then $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset\ldots$, and $E = \bigcup_1^\infty E_n$. Therefore we may apply continuity from below to obtain
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_1^n A_i\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n) = \mu(E)=\mu\left(\bigcup_1^\infty A_i\right).
$$

It follows from the countable additivity property of measures. Set $B_1 = A_1$, $B_i = A_i\setminus A_{i-1}$. Note that the $B_i$-s are pairwise disjoint, $\bigcup_1^n B_i = \bigcup_1^n A_i$, and $\bigcup_1^\infty B_i=\bigcup_1^\infty A_i$. Can you finish?

Comment: Have you proved that Lebesgue measure satisfies continuity from below? If not, that might be the issue here.

Comment: I haven't proved continuity from below, and I don't see it in my textbook either. Is it hard to prove? If not, could you please perhaps show a sketch?

Comment: Oh, maybe I just got it. Using your $E_i$ notation: $E=E_1\cup (E_2-E_1)\cup (E_3-E_2)\cup\ldots$ (disjoint union), so $\mu(E)=\mu(E_1)+\mu(E_2-E_1)+\mu(E_3-E_2)+\ldots$. The sum of the first $n$ terms on the right is $\mu(E_n)$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(E_n)=\mu(E)$.

Comment: @PJMiller Nice! I just added exactly the same thing to my post. I doubt that your textbook actually omits this property: it is very fundamental to measure theory.

Comment: Thanks, kigen. I just found it hidden as one of the exercises (and without the name "continuity from below") :)

Answer (score 1):

Define $B_n = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}A_i$. Then $B_n\subseteq B_{n+1}$. By continuity from below we have that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(B_n)=\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i\right)=\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right).$$

This last equality follows because the union of all of the $B_n$ is certainly the same as the union of all of the $A_n$. Thus we are done.