# why $\cup_{1}^{n}B_i=\cup_{1}^{n} A_i ?$

Tags: measure-theory

This  user is not active since for many days  so i post the question here again

I have taken the answer from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/535294/557708)

i have some doubt on this answer .My doubt is given below in red box

[image]

**My attempt** : Im thinking like this $\cup_{1}^{n}B_i =  A_1 \cup (A_2-A_1) \cup (A_3 -A_2.)......\cup (A_n-A_{n-1})$

$\cup_{1}^{n} A_i = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup .......\cup A_n$

I can clearly see that  $A_1 \cup (A_2-A_1) \cup (A_3 -A_2.)......\cup (A_n-A_{n-1}) \neq A_1 \cup A_2 \cup .......\cup A_n $

Then why $\cup_{1}^{n}B_i=\cup_{1}^{n} A_i ?$

Comment: Hint: for each $x\in \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$, consider the SMALLEST $j$ such that $x\in A_j$.

Comment: You clearly see that $A_1\cup(A_2\setminus A_1)\ne A_1\cup A_2$?

Comment: ya @kimchilover   since $A_2 - A_1 \neq A_2$

Comment: You should rethink this

Comment: Draw a venn-diagram to convince yourself that $A_1\cup(A_2\setminus A_1) = A_1\cup A_2$ (and if you're still not convinced see the answer below; then finally use induction to prove it for all $n$)

Comment: thanks u @peek-a-boo  oh ya i got !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\cup(B/A)=A\cup (B\cap A^c)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup A^c)=(A\cup B)\cap \Omega=A\cup B$