# Prove: if $f:[0,1]^2\to R$ is continuous, $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta: \mu\{x:f(x)\in(0,\delta)\}<\epsilon$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have come up with a proof, but I am not sure it is correct. Let $S = [0,1]^2\cap\{x:f(x)\geq0\}$. The set $\{x:f(x)\geq0\}$ is closed and $[0,1]^2$ is compact, so $S$ is compact. Suppose that $f$ is strictly positive on $S$. Because $f$ is continous and $S$ is compact, $f$ attains a minimum on $S$. Letting $\delta = \min_{x \in S}f(x)$ yields: $\{x:f(x) \in (0,\delta)\} = \emptyset \Rightarrow   \mu\{x:f(x) \in (0,\delta)\}=0$.
Suppose that $\exists x:f(x) = 0$. Let $Y = \{x:f(x)=0\}$. Because $Y$ is measurable, $\forall \epsilon$ $\exists$ an open set $O:Y\subset O $ and $\mu(O \backslash S)<\epsilon$. Because $O^c$ is closed and $S$ is compact, $O^c \cap S$ is compact. Let $\delta = \min_{x \in O^c \cap S}f(x)$. Then $\forall x \notin O \backslash Y:f(x) \notin (0,\delta)$. Hence $f(x) \in (0,\delta)\Rightarrow x \in O \backslash Y \Rightarrow \mu\{x:f(x)\in(0,\delta)<\epsilon\}$.

Comment: I assume you mean $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in fact, this proposition only requires $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ to be measurable, where $A$ is a measure space with finite measure.

For consider the fact that $f^{-1}((0, \infty)) \subseteq A$ is a measurable set. And consider that $f^{-1}((0, \infty)) = f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}_+} (\frac{1}{n}, \infty)) = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}_+} f^{-1}((\frac{1}{n}, \infty))$.

Then $\mu(f^{-1}((0, \infty))) = \mu(\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}_+} f^{-1}((\frac{1}{n}, \infty))) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mu(\bigcup\limits_{m = 1}^n f^{-1}(\frac{1}{m}, \infty)) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mu(f^{-1}(\frac{1}{n}, \infty))$.

So take $n$ such that $\mu(f^{-1}((0, \infty))) - \mu(f^{-1}((\frac{1}{n}, \infty)) < \epsilon$. Then $\mu(f^{-1}((0, \frac{1}{n}])) < \epsilon$. Then $\mu(f^{-1}((0, \frac{1}{n}))) < \epsilon$. So take $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I do mean $\delta>0$ and $\epsilon>0$. It is not obvious why $\mu(\cup_{N_{+}}f^{-1}(\frac{1}{n},\infty)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(f^{-1}(\frac{1}{n},\infty))$

Comment: @ArseniySamsonov It's always the case that $\mu(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty A_n) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mu(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n A_n)$. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535285/798694. In this case, $\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n (1/i, \infty) = (1/n, \infty)$. And note that unions commute with $f^{-1}$. So $\bigcup\limits_{m = 1}^n f^{-1}((1/m, \infty)) = f^{-1}((1/m, \infty))$.